# What is a guest OS in VMWare player and how do I enable auto-login for Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-workstation

Problem:
[image: Problem Is Here!]

I want to enable autologin for my Ubuntu 13.10 that I'm running in VMWare player. But it does not allow me because the "guest OS does not support it".

What is a guest OS? How can I make a none guest so I can enable autologin?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guest OS is the OS installed inside the VMWare Player, so in this case Ubuntu 13.10.
Automatic login in Ubuntu 13.10 settings is greyed out, because you need to click on the "Unlock" button that is on the top right part of the window (it can't be seen on the screenshot). Hold ALT and left mouse button on the any part of the window to move that window to the left, and you will see the Unlock button. Press it, enter your password, and then you can enable "Automatic Login".
I guess there is no need to enable "Autologin" option in VMWare Player settings for this to work.